# Probability and Name of Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ has PDF $f_X$ given by

\begin{align*}
f_X (x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\alpha x_0^\alpha} {x^{\alpha+1}} &\text{if $x ≥ x_0$,}\\ 
0 &\text{if $x < x_0$,}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
￼where $x_0 \gt 0$ and $\alpha \gt 0$ are given fixed parameters. What is the distribution of  $\log(\frac{X}{x_0})$? Give PDF and the name of the distribution.

I am little confused how to start this. 
Let $Y=log(X/x_0) $, then $ F_Y= P(log(X/x_0) <= y)=F_X (x_0*e^y) $. Am I on the right track with this one?

Comment: At least correct you latex (pareto I think)

Comment: pareto distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Pareto distribution. The natural logarithm of $X/x_0$ is exponentially distributed. See more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).

Comment: Why does the question ask for PDF when PDF is already given? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @DeeChantelle I guess you need to determine the pdf of $\log (X/x_0)$.

Comment: Let $Y=log(X/x_0) $, then $ F_Y= P(log(X/x_0) <= y)=F_X (x_0*e^y) $. Am I on the right track with this one?

Comment: @DeeChantelle Yes. And since
\begin{align*}
F_X(x)=\begin{cases}1-(x_0/x)^{\alpha}&\text{if $x\geq x_0$,}\\0&\text{if $x<x_0$,}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
you have that
\begin{align*}
F_Y(y)=F_X(x_0\exp(y))=\begin{cases}1-\exp(-\alpha y)&\text{ if $y\geq0$,}\\ 0&\text{ if $y<0$.}\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: So then we need to differentiate and we get $f_Y (y) = αe^(−αy)$  if $y ≥0$ and 0 otherwise ? So that should be the pdf we are looking for?

Comment: @DeeChantelle Exactly. This is the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).